# How can you compile a .pyc file into a .exe file? I can't use auto-py-to-exe or pyinstaller for it, because they don't accept bytes

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have a script that i compiled into a .pyc file, so that the code is encrypted into bytes. How can i turn this .pyc file into a .exe file? I know you can decompile .pyc scripts with uncompyle6, but that's okay, I still want to have an extra layer for my script.

Comment: Did you throw away the original .py after you created the .pyc from it?  *That's* what any .exe converter is going to want as input - they need to be able to analyze your source code, to know what modules you `import`, and therefore need to be included in the .exe.

Comment: No, i didn't throw away the original file. What I want to do tho, is convert the file to a .pyc file and turn the .pyc file into a .exe file.

Comment: That's simply not the way it works.  The process of turning a .py into a .exe is going to produce the equivalent of a .pyc anyway, doing that part of the job yourself is not going to help anything.

Comment: What's your motivation? Are you simply trying to hide your script from the user? If so, Python is probably not the ideal language for your use case.